# pandas data format to preserve DateTimeIndex

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, file-format

I do a lot of work with data that has DateTime indexes and multi-indexes. Saving and reading as a .csv is tedious because every time I have to reset_index and name it "date" then when I read again, I have to convert the date back to a datetime and set the index. What format will help me avoid this? I'd prefer something open source - for instance I think SAS and Stata will do this, but they are proprietary.

Comment: CSV is text. It does not have a datatype. You can not save with specific data types in csv.

Comment: If you are reading and writing from the same set-up (and only if), use pickle: `df.to_pickle('file.pkl'); df = pd_read_pickle('file.pkl')`, it's serialized and fast. Or consider HDF5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

feather was made for this:
https://github.com/wesm/feather

> Feather provides binary columnar serialization for data frames. It is
>   designed to make reading and writing data frames efficient, and to
>   make sharing data across data analysis languages easy. This initial
>   version comes with bindings for python (written by Wes McKinney) and R
>   (written by Hadley Wickham).
>
> Feather uses the Apache Arrow columnar memory specification to
>   represent binary data on disk. This makes read and write operations
>   very fast. This is particularly important for encoding null/NA values
>   and variable-length types like UTF8 strings.
>
> Feather is a part of the broader Apache Arrow project. Feather defines
>   its own simplified schemas and metadata for on-disk representation.
>
> Feather currently supports the following column types:
>
> A wide range of numeric types (int8, int16, int32, int64, uint8,
>   uint16, uint32, uint64, float, double). Logical/boolean values. Dates,
>   times, and timestamps. Factors/categorical variables that have fixed
>   set of possible values. UTF-8 encoded strings. Arbitrary binary data.